# Как в Stm32CubeIDE добавить свои файлы

Tags: c++, c, stm32

При попытке добавить свой файл с функциями и сделать include в main.c - вылезает ошибка.
Как будто оно его два раза импорит...

```
// ошибка
prog.c:1: multiple definition of `loop'
prog.c:1: first defined here
```

.

```
// main.c
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "../Src/prog.c"
/* USER CODE END Includes */
```

.

```
// prog.c
void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Опять кто-то инклудит C-файл...

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы запускаете компилятор, он компилирует каждый c-файл по отдельности: сначала `main.c`, потом `prog.c`. Директива `#include` выполняет простую подстановку одного файла в другой: в вашем случае всё содержимое файла `prog.c` попадает в файл `main.c`. Таким образом у вас действительно оказываются две одинаковые функции: одна в файле `main.c`, другая в файле `prog.c`.

Вам нужно создать дополнительный файл `prog.h`, в нём прописать прототип функции `loop`:

```
void loop();
```

и подключать в main уже его. При этом не забывайте про защиту от множественного включения:

```
//prog.h
#ifndef PROG_H
#define PROG_H

void loop();

#endif
```

---

```
// prog.c
#include "prog.h"
void loop() {

}
```